# snap.svg: applying a function to many objects

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I have created a number of circle objects using snap.svg, have added text to each, and grouped each pair of circles and text into unique groups. I would now like to apply a common animation to all of them that should take place upon a double click. Is there a quick way to apply an event triggered animation to all of these objects quickly? I tried creating an array of all my objects and then iterating through it, applying my event function on each pass of the for loop. It doesn't seem to work though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show some code as mentioned, as a base I would probably do something like this, changing the selector as required.

```
s.selectAll('group').forEach( function( el ) { el.dbclick( myDoubleClickFunc ) } );

function myDoubleClickFunc() {
   this.animate(....)
};
```